# Align variable height child div to bottom of variable height parent div, while another child pushes it down

Tags: html, css

The title is probably more complex than the idea itself. Below is an image showing what I need. There are simple rules:

- A is a div with min-height: 800px; if B+C>A (in height), then A should expand to fit both B and C. (Standard behavior).
- B is a div that is variable height
  and needs to always be aligned to top of A, regardless of the height
  of C.
- C is a div that has variable height and needs always be aligned
  to the bottom of A, regardless of the height of B.
- The heights of B & C are determined by their contents (text mostly).

[image: align variable height div to bottom of parent]

- The leftmost image shows what it should look like when the the
  heights of B + C < height of A. (Min-height 800px applies)
- The center image shows what should happen if B + C > A (B has grown
  in height, C has stayed the same, and thus, A has also grown in height).
- The rightmost image shows what should happen if B + C > A (both B and
  C have grown in height, and thus, A has also grown in height).

Is this even possible with pure HTML/CSS and no Javascript? The execution environment does not have Javascript capability (or if it has, it's a very limited one), so I probably cannot rely on JS-based solutions.

My own first attempt was to make A `position: relative;` and make C `position:absolute; bottom: 0;` but then when B grows, it will overlap with C, because C is no longer in the page flow.

Then I thought about giving B a `min-height` that would push C to the bottom, but that doesn't work either because C does not have a fixed height, which means I cannot specify a fixed `min-height` for B.

I also tried working with making A `display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom;`, but that would then push both B & C to the bottom. Perhaps if I could make B fill the rest of the available space, I could make this approach work?

I created this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/376rp/ so that anyone who has any ideas has a jump-start. Please note: there are two "B"-blocks there (with a yellow background). The correct solution should probably work with any number of "B"-blocks.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably as close as you'll get with pure CSS:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/zALfo

```
<div class="paper">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</div>

.paper {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.paper .footer {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

There isn't really a way to prevent the outer element from expanding when its contents get too big.  If your device doesn't have access to JS, there's a pretty good chance Flexbox won't work either.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Actually, the outer element should expand as the inner contents expand. It doesn't have a fixed height. I only specified that it should have a `min-height`, but my drawings may have made this confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know you are looking for a pure CSS solution but maybe this could help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/kb6nW/6/

**HTML**

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var margin = 10;
var minHeight = 250 + margin;
var as = document.getElementsByClassName('a');
var i;

for(i = 0; i < as.length; i++) {

    var height = minHeight - as[i].offsetHeight;
    var x = as[i].getElementsByClassName('b')[0];

    x.style.marginBottom = Math.max(margin, height) + 'px';
}
```